# Generate Dummy column into Main Table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to generate a dummy column for the main table.

Currently, I do by merging but it is not working.

`dummy_col` should be in `PXXXXX` format where XXXXX can be random number.

```
Main Table
| id | col1 |
|  1 |  a   |
|  2 |  b   |

Dummy Data
| dummy_col |
|    p02    |
|    p01    |

Desired Output
| id | col1 | dummy_col |
|  1 |  a   |    p02    |
|  2 |  b   |    p01    |
```

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE main_table
ADD COLUMN dummy_col Text;
UPDATE main_table SET dummy_col = (SELECT ('P' || generate_series(1000001,10931606)))
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Can you clarify the rules for merging a given value in the dummy table with a given row in the main table?

Comment: no rules. Basically, just merge them. There is no relationship between them.

Comment: What isn't working? What error message do you get?

Comment: @NevilleKuyt SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression.